# Make Angular application interact with React build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, architecture

I'm currently working on a project where I have to integrate a React widget into an Angular application. To make the explanation short, my component is basically a chatbot.
Here is the App.tsx ( The React application code is written with TypeScript). For instance, here is the App component ( boostrapping point of the application ) :

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import { Widget, addResponseMessage,saveResponseMessage, setQuickButtons, toggleMsgLoader, setCarousel, renderCustomComponent, setCustomer, loadAllMessages } from '../index';
import { GlobalState } from '../src/store/types'
import {CarouselData} from '../src/components/Carousel/index'
import {CardComponent} from '../src/components/Card/index'
import { Video } from '../shared/interfaces/video.interface';
import {VideoComponent} from '../src/components/Video/index';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { User } from '../src/store/types';
import { saveUserMessage } from '../src/store/dispatcher';
export default function App() {
  const customer = useSelector((state: GlobalState) => state.customer.customer);
  const avatar = require('../assets/avatar.svg') as string;
  const bot = require('../assets/bot.svg') as string;
  const populateMessages = (customer:User | null) =>{
    if (customer?.uid){
        const uid = customer.uid
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/messages/reset",{message : ''}).then(() => {
      setQuickButtons([
        {label : 'Nike', value : 'Nike'},
        {label : 'Adidas', value : 'Adidas'},
        {label : 'Puma', value : 'Puma'},
        {label : 'Louis Vuitton', value : 'Louis Vuitton'}
    ])
    }).then(() =>
      loadAllMessages(uid)
    )
    }
  }
  const handleTextClicked = (e : any)=>
  {
    addResponseMessage('Selected :' + e);
    setCarousel([]);
  }
  const handleLearnMoreClicked = (newMessage : string) =>{
    addResponseMessage(newMessage);
  }

  const handleQuickButtonClicked = (e: any) => 
  {
    saveUserMessage(e,customer?.uid);
    handleNewUserMessage(e);
    setQuickButtons([],'');
  }
useEffect(() => {
  populateMessages(customer)

},[])
 
  const handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage: any) => { 
    toggleMsgLoader();
    setQuickButtons([]);
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/messages/send",{ message : newMessage }).then((data : any) =>{

      if (data.status === 200){
        console.log(data);
      // show message through component type
      if(data.data.component === 'card')
      {
        toggleMsgLoader();
        renderCustomComponent(CardComponent,{items : data.data.items,learnMore : handleLearnMoreClicked},true);
      } 
      else if (data.data.component === 'carousel')
      { 
        toggleMsgLoader();
        if (data.data.items && data.data.items.length){
          renderCustomComponent(CarouselData,data.data.items,true);
        }
        else
        {
          addResponseMessage("No items found !")
        }
        if (data.data.buttons){
        const buttons = data.data.buttons.map(button =>{
          return {label : button,value : button}
        })
        setQuickButtons(buttons);
      }
      }
      else if (data.data.component == 'video')
      {
        console.log(data.data)
        const videoData : Video = {
          src : data.data.items.video,
          secondText : data.data.items.secondText,
          learnMore : data.data.items.learnMore,
        }
        toggleMsgLoader();
        renderCustomComponent(VideoComponent,videoData,true);
        setQuickButtons([{ label: 'Yes', value: 'yes' }, { label: 'No', value: 'no' }],'Does this video meet your needs ?');
      }
      else if (data.data.component === 'text')
      {
        addResponseMessage(data.data.message);
        toggleMsgLoader();
      }
      return data;
    }
    })
    // this is response message
    .then(data =>{
      saveResponseMessage(data,customer?.uid)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      saveResponseMessage(err.response.data.errorMessage,customer?.uid)
    })
  }

    return (
      
      <div>
        {customer?.uid &&
        <Widget
          title="Welcome"
          subtitle="Test Virtual assistant"
          senderPlaceHolder="Type a question..."
          handleNewUserMessage={handleNewUserMessage}
          handleQuickButtonClicked={handleQuickButtonClicked}
          emojis={true}
          imagePreview={true}
          profileAvatar={avatar}
          handleTextClicked={handleTextClicked}
          launcherOpenImg={bot}
          launcherCloseImg={bot}
        />}

      </div>
    );
}
```

The functionality given by the APIs isn't important here. The most important part is what the functional component returns i.e the Widget component.
I created a build for this application, that was later on mounted into an angular application.
The build was created with webpack. It created an index.js file that contains all of the javascript and a styles.css for the style of the app.
I referenced these into my Angular index.html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularHybrid</title>

  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/javascript/styles.css">
  <script src="./assets/javascript/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>

  </div>
  <app-root></app-root>
  
  <div id="root"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

The widget is perfectly working on the angular app. Yet, there is a small problem. I need to send some props from the angular application into the React script. I was wondering if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Signals to add a signal to the global scope and then use it in both apps. You are also able to use local storage for this purpose.

for more information read this link: https://dev.to/ryansolid/a-hands-on-introduction-to-fine-grained-reactivity-3ndf